# Simplify dataframe comparison for filtering data

Tags: python, pandas

How can I simplify the following so that I can easily change the filter condition to something like `GW_filter = np.arange(6,11)`

```
df = df.loc[(df.GW == 6) | (df.GW == 7) | (df.GW == 8) | (df.GW == 9) | (df.GW == 10)]
```

Comment: df.GW.isin or df.GW.between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using mask?

```
>>> mask = (df.GW >= 6) | (df.GW <= 10)

>>> df[mask]
```

#### EDIT

@Quang Hoang provides even a better solution - using between

```
>>> df.GW.between(6,10)
```